# Drug Delivery Economics : Max Path of Length k?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am a drug dealer with a map of delivery routes that are each worth a certain amount. But I can't cover the whole area, I just have to fight out my little bit of turf. However, I can choose which bit of turf I can fight out.

The vertexes of this graph are street corners, and all streets are the same length **and 1 way**. Some streets are worth a LOT more than others. I want to find the maximum beat to walk, such that the number of street corners I have to pass is at a minimum. All paths start at 42nd Street Subway and End at Roosevelt Island Tram.

I have had a quick look around the nets but doesn't seem like something I remember seeing anywhere.

Calculating the maximum weight/flow/cost path is easy **on DAGs** using dynamic programming.

But what if we are also required to find such a max path that is AS SHORT AS POSSIBLE? **Well, we can iterate over all the max paths of length k for k near some ballpark value. But, how to get max path of length k?**

Any ideas where to find pointers to this?

**EDIT 1**

Okay..I have a feeling Floyd-Warshall can do max path at specific length. This could be good enough, I can just run it over all possible lengths. But...any better ideas?

**EDIT 2**

Amended to refer to only DAGs.

**EDIT 3**

Floyd-Warshall can do max path of specific length, k : Meaning, combining DAG max path with using Floyd Warshall to obtain the shortest (in the number of edges) path between any vertex and the final stop. So at any vertex in the max path algorithm, killing the search branch at that vertex when the sum of the current number of edges (of the current max path) + the (Floyd-Warshall determined) min number of edges between that vertex and the final stop will exceed our specific length, k.

**EDIT 4**

I think I have an answer.

To find max path of length k for this graph let's assume that for any node in the graph we know the minimum number of edges between that node and the end point.

So we just run max path algorithm like so, making sure we check that the minimum number of edges possible for a given branch is below our exclusion bound

In this code, the graph is a dictionary of edges indexed by their starting vertexes, each edge is a tuple (destination_edge,weight). This algorithm maximizes weight, but ensures the path it returns is no longer than the parameter k:

```
def maxpathoflength(k,start_vertex,graph_out_edges,memory,frame_size):
    # first of all we leverage dynamic programming to save any results we have checked before
    if start_vertex in memory:
        return memory[start_vertex]
    # otherwise we calculate it
    # first we set the current maximum gold at this vertex
    maxgold = 0
    # corresponding to the following maximum path
    maxpath = [start_vertex]
    #then we check to see if we have broken our k-length path constraint
    if k < 0:
        # we failed, yet somehow we should never make it to here anyway
        return { 'gold' : maxgold, 'path' : maxpath }
        # if on the other hand k were equal to zero and this was the end point
        # we would have succeeded
    # we save this size since we can use it to calculate the lower bound 
    # on the number of edges required to get to the finish from this vertex 
    graph_size = len(graph_out_edges)
    # we get the edges adjacent to start_vertex
    # they are all out_edges, the graph has the DAG property

    # the graph also has this property : there are no out edges from the last vertex :
    if start_vertex > graph_size - 1:
        return { 'gold' : maxgold, 'path' : maxpath }
    out_edges = graph_out_edges[start_vertex]
    print 'Out edges: ' + str(out_edges)
    for edge in out_edges:
        # each edge is stored as a 2-tuple (to_vertex,edge_weight)
        arrival_vertex = edge[0]
        edge_weight = edge[1]
        # the following property holds for this graph, hence we can know the lower bound on edges of any path from this vertex
        min_edges_from_arrival_vertex_to_end = ceil((1.0*graph_size - int(arrival_vertex))/frame_size)
        # and so we can determine if we want should search it or not
        if min_edges_from_arrival_vertex_to_end > k-1:
            print 'Skipping this edge'
            continue
        # or if this branch is ok
        # we search down this branch and take 1 off the edges
        # remaining
        # we search it and find the result of searching it is...
        result = maxpathoflength(k-1,arrival_vertex,graph_out_edges,memory,frame_size)  
        gold = edge_weight + result.get('gold')
        path = result.get('path') 
        # if that result is greater than our current best
        if gold > maxgold:
            # we make that result our new personal best
            maxgold = gold
            maxpath = [start_vertex] + path

    # our return value is what we found the maximum to be from this vertex
    returnvalue = { 'gold' : maxgold, 'path' : maxpath }
    # we save this so we never ever have to do this again
    memory[start_vertex] = returnvalue
    # and send it back to up to the calling function 
    return returnvalue
```

Comment: `Calculating the maximum weight/flow/cost path is easy using dynamic programming` - I must be misunderstanding you, since [longest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard)... What exactly did you have in mind? (And no, Floyd-Warshall won't find max path - it finds shortest path)

Comment: Yep, sorry, referring only to DAGs. Will edit to ammend. Also I can walk the beat without ever visiting same vertex twice, all streets are 1 way and flow roughly West to East.

Comment: And yes, Floyd-Warshall will find max path of specific length -- when combined with max path, as explained more clearly above.

Comment: Yes, it can with the edit of DAG (can be abstracted by giving each edge weight of `w'(e,v)= -w(e,v)` - and there are no cycles, so obviously no negative cycles - and the shortest path with the new weight is the max weight of original `w`).

Comment: Cool, so it looks like with my Floyd-Warshall and your negative edge weights we have this thing licked. Is that about right? Basically...Find shortest ( most negative ) path using G' and Floyd-Warshall, and floyd-warshall...but how do compute max path of length k?